# Remainders problem ; Remainders of $3N$ and $4N$ are given with $D$. How to find remainder of $N$ with $D$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A number, $3N$ when divided by $D$, leaves a remainder of $13$, where $N$ and $D$ are natural numbers.  If $4N$ is divided by $D$, the remainder is $9$.  What will be the remainder when $N$ is divided by $D$ ?

---

Please provide a hint on how to solve this

I can infer that $D>13$ and $D$ should be a factor of both $3N-13$ and $4N-9$  , but can't seem to apply it, should I take random $D$ values and solve , how to proceed?

Comment: Try to show that if $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod{m}$, then $a-c \equiv b-d \pmod{m}$.

Comment: Another approach: $D | (3N-13)$ and $D | (4N-9)$, thus $D | \gcd(3N-13, 4N-9)$. If $g=\gcd(3N-13, 4N-9)$, then $g | 4(3N-13)-3(4N-9)=-25$. Thus $D | 25$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $3N=xD+13$ and $4N=yD+9$ where $x\lt y$ and both are natural numbers.

By simply subtracting, we can get that $N=(y-x)D-4$.
Thus, the remainder of $N\div D$ is $-4$ *(let's ignore how it's negative for now)*

Now, to sound more "professional"...

> We'll use [the notation $N\equiv-4\pmod D$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation#Basic_example)

**So, the answer is $D-4$?**
Actually, we can go even further!
$$N\equiv-4\pmod D$$
$$\text{which means...}$$
$$3N\equiv-12\pmod D$$

So, $3N\equiv13\pmod D\equiv-12\pmod D$. What does that mean?

It means that $[\text{something}]\cdot D+13=[\text{something}]\cdot D-12$. Let's name those $\text{[something]}$s $x$ and $z$,  where $z\gt x$. So:

$$xD+13=zD-12$$
$$25=(z-x)D$$
...and $25$ must be a multiple of $D$. Though, since $D\gt13$ (as you said), this means $D=25$. A big revelation!

So, $N\equiv-4\pmod D\implies N\equiv25-4\pmod D$ and $N\div D$ has the remainder $21$.